# Should .webpack folder be committed to source code? Serverless Framework - serverless-bundle

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, serverless-framework

I'd like to understand if .webpack should be committed to source code repository?

I'm using serverless-bundle within Serverless Framework to be able to write ES6 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will answer your question but base on the documentation of serverless-bundle. Everything will be manage by the serverless-bundle and to change the config of the webpack is on the serverless.yml so I think you dont need to commit the .webpack on your source code.

https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/serverless-bundle#options

and base on their advance options they dont support the customization of the webpack and babel.

https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/serverless-bundle#advanced-options